# Get process Id from process name

Tags: java, windows, scala, jna, pid

I am using Scala and I couldn't find something that would give me the PrcoessID from the Processname. Neither in Java, Scala or Winapi.

At the moment I am using `FindWindowA` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, but I would prefer something that would give me an array

```
val process: Array[Int] = GetProcessIdFromExeName("Notepad")
```

So if I would have 10 instances of Notepad, I could access them with `process(0-9)`

I know that something like this exists in .NET, but is there something similar in the WINAPI or Java/Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to run  `tasklist` and parse the output. See this resource for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows

You can also use WMI. It is very simple to write JScript or VBScript that performs WMI query and prints the output, So you can run it from either java or Scala process and parse the output. WMI provides more options than `tasklist`.

If you choose WMI you can also call it utilizing one of existing java-to-com libraries e.g. JaWin, Jintegra, JInterop.

Answer (score 0):

Old question; however, I wrote this class to a while ago to do this :

```
 public class TaskList {
    public static final String PROCESS_NAME = "tasklist";
    private static final String LINE_FORMAT = "%-25s %14s %-16s %14s %15s\n";

    public static Process getTaskListProcess() throws IOException {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PROCESS_NAME);
    }

    List<TaskListEntry> taskListEntries;
    boolean hasRun;

    public TaskList() {
        taskListEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void run() {
        if (hasRun) {
            // intentions of running this twice is not clear so throw exception
            String err = "TaskList can only be run once";
            throw new IllegalStateException(err);
        }

        try {
            Process proc = getProcess();
            List<String> lines = Processes.getAllLines(proc);

            String[] seperators = lines.get(2).split(" ");
            if (seperators.length < 5) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Incorrect number of seperators parsed");
            }

            // Remove header and separators
            lines = lines.subList(4, lines.size() - 1);

            for (String line : lines) {
                taskListEntries.add(new TaskListEntry(seperators, line));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String err = "Error resolving process";
            throw new IllegalStateException(err, e);
        }
    }

    Process getProcess() throws IOException {
        return getTaskListProcess();
    }

    public List<TaskListEntry> getTaskListEntries() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(taskListEntries);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String sep = "============================";
        String headers = String.format(LINE_FORMAT, "Image Name", "PID", "Session Name", "Session#", "Mem Usage");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(headers);
        builder.append(sep).append(" ")
            .append(sep.substring(17)).append(" ")
            .append(sep.substring(9)).append(" ")
            .append(sep.substring(17)).append(" ")
            .append(sep.substring(13)).append('\n');

        for(TaskListEntry entry : getTaskListEntries()) {
            builder.append(entry.toString());
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public class TaskListEntry {
        private TaskListEntry(String[] seperators, String line) {
            try {
                int start = 0;
                int end = start + seperators[0].length() + 1;
                this.image = line.substring(start, end).trim();

                start = end;
                end = start + seperators[1].length() + 1;
                this.pid = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(start, end).trim());

                start = end;
                end = start + seperators[2].length() + 1;
                this.sessionName = line.substring(start, end).trim();

                start = end;
                end = start + seperators[3].length() + 1;
                this.sessionNum = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(start, end).trim());

                start = end;
                end = start + seperators[4].length();
                this.memUsage = line.substring(start, end).trim();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                String format = "Unable to parse line {%s} with seperator {%s}";
                String msg = String.format(format, line, Arrays.toString(seperators));
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg, e);
            }

        }

        String image;
        int pid;
        String sessionName;
        int sessionNum;
        String memUsage;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(LINE_FORMAT, image, pid, sessionName, sessionNum, memUsage);
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public int getPid() {
            return pid;
        }

        public void setPid(int pid) {
            this.pid = pid;
        }

        public String getSessionName() {
            return sessionName;
        }

        public void setSessionName(String sessionName) {
            this.sessionName = sessionName;
        }

        public int getSessionNum() {
            return sessionNum;
        }

        public void setSessionNum(int sessionNum) {
            this.sessionNum = sessionNum;
        }

        public String getMemUsage() {
            return memUsage;
        }

        public void setMemUsage(String memUsage) {
            this.memUsage = memUsage;
        }
    }


 public static void main(String [] args){
        TaskList tasks = new TaskList();
        tasks.run();
        tasks.getTaskListEntries();
        Optional<TaskListEntry> entry  = tasks.getTaskListEntries()
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getImage().equals("notepad++.exe"))
                .findFirst();

        if(entry.isPresent()) {
            logger.info(entry.get());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the referenced Processes class

```
public class Processes {

    public static BufferedReader getProcessReader(Process p) {
        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        return new BufferedReader(reader);
    }

    public static List<String> getAllLines(Process p) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = getProcessReader(p)) {
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
            return lines;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "Reader is not in a readable state";
            throw new IllegalStateException(msg, e);
        }
    }

    private Processes() {
        // This is a utility method
    }
}
```